# reporting servcies 0x7 KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN only on server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssrs

I have Reporting Services configured on Windows Server 2008 R2. The reporting services is running under domain account and so its AppPool. I am accessing the site through a custom domain.

The problem is when I access the site through a custom domain on the same server on which the reporting services is running, IE keeps on asking me to enter credentials and I get `0x7  KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN` error in my event log and I am not able to log in. However, if I access the same site through another machine in the same network, I am able to log on successfully. So, this happens only if i access the site from server on which reporting services is installed.

What configuration am I missing?

I have set SPN `HTTP/www.mydomain.com` for the server on which reporting services is installed, also have set the host header in IIS and reporting services configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the setting

```
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Allow</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
```

to

```
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
```

and everything seems to be working, strange!

Answer (score 0):

SSRS generally works the same whether you're on the box, or remote.... I presume from the references to IIS that you are using SQL Server 2005 rather than a later version. Gulp - have you tried a reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did a restart, but no luck :(